# Aliased rasterization: why sampling pixel at center?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, rendering

Both OpenGL and Direct3D use pixel's center as a sample point during rasterization (without antialiasing).

For example here is the quote from [D3D11 rasterization rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc627092(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Any pixel center which falls inside a triangle is drawn

I tried to find out what is the reason to use `(0.5, 0.5)` instead of, say, `(0.0, 0.0)` or whatever else in range of `0.0 - 1.0f` for both x and y.

The result might be translated a little, but does it really matter? Does it produce some visible artifacts? May be, it makes some algorithms harder to implement? Or it's just a convention?

Again, I don't talk about multisampling here.

So what is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer mainly focuses on the OP's comment on 
Cagkan Toptas answer:

> Thanx for the answer, but my question is: why does it give better
>   results? Does it at all? If yes, what is the explanation?"

It depends on how you define "better" results. From an image qualioty perspective, it does not change much, as long as the primitves are not specifically aligned (after the projection).
Using just one sample at (0,0) instead (0.5, 0.5) will just *shift* the scene by half a pixel (in both axis, of course). In the general case of aribitrary placed primitves, the average error should be the same.

However, if you want "pixel-exact" drawing (i.e. for text, and UI, and also full-screen post-processing effects), you just would have to take the convention of the underlying implementation into account, and both conventions would work.

One advantage of the "center at half integers" rule is that you can get the integer pixel coordinates (with respect to the sample locations) of the nearest pixel by a simple `floor(floating_point_coords)` operation, which is simpler than rounding to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the answer to your problem, but I try to answer your question from [ray tracing](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15462-s09/www/lec/13/lec13.pdf) perspective.

In ray tracing, you can get color of every single points in the scene. But since we have a limited amount of pixel, you need to downsample to your image to your screen pixels.

In ray tracing, if you use 1 ray per pixel, we generally choose center point to create our ray which gives the most correct render results. In the image below, I try to show the difference when you choose a corner of pixel or center. The distance will get bigger when your object is far from the rendering screen.

[image]

If you use more than one ray for each pixel, lets say 5 rays (4 corners + 1 center) and average the result, you will of course get more realistic image ( Will handle aliasing problems much better) However it will be slower as you guess.

So, it is probably the same idea that opengl and directX take one sample for each pixel instead of multisampling and taking average (Performance issues) and center point is probably giving the best result.

**EDIT :**

For area rasterization, center of pixel is used because if center of pixel remains inside Area, it is guaranteed that **at least 50% of pixel** is inside the shape.(Except shape corners) That's why since the proportion is greater than half that pixel is colored.

For other corner selections there is no general rule. Lets look at example image below. The black point (bottom left) is outside of area and should not be drawn (And when you look at it more than half of pixel is outside. However if you look at blue point %80 of pixel is inside area but since bottom left corner is outside area it shouldn't be drawn

[image]

Comment: Thanx for the answer, but my question is: why does it give better results? Does it at all? If yes, what is the explanation?

Comment: @loreglean I edited the question and try to explain better. Hope it is usefull . Sorry for bad MS paint skill :P

Comment: Well, I'm aware that for simple cases it might guarantee that area is bigger then 50%. But this rule does not hold in general, as you said, with corners. If you will move camera far enough there will be corners in every pixel and this won't give any benefits. So can this be a real reason to use pixel center?

Comment: Although, I guess, it's better then giving no benefits at all from any distance...

Comment: @loreglean since we have limited pixel size, we are quantizing(digitalizing) the output. It definitely introduce errors to us like this problem there is no escape. What we do is trying to minimize this error. If you move camera far your shape will disappear it is true. But you simply cannot render scene to a microscobic level.

Comment: It is still not clear if it gives any visible benefits. As I wrote in the question, it will just move primitive for just one pixel in most cases (because if pixel is inside any sample will do). @derhass answer below states the same. It's a shame there is no in depth information about this choice, or I didn't search well enough. But I agree that 50% area thing seems reasonable

Comment: @loreglean: Well, if you think of pixels as small "area elements" (which some do and some don't), using the center as sample location appears just as the most intuitive choice to me (YMMV). But as the distances between the sample locations are the same no matter wich location in the pixel you chosse, the potential aliasing artifacts due to the discrecte sampling are also the same in general.